# Schema in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to change the eav attribute table like

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = ‘lastname’
```

How to update the eav attribute table without using query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update attribute using `upgradeData` like below code

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Setup; 
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface 
{
    public function __construct(
        EavSetup $eavSetupFactory
        ) 
    { 
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
    } 

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) { 
        $setup->startSetup();
        $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(4,135,'is_used_for_promo_rules',1,null); 
        $setup->endSetup(); 
    } 

}
```

In above code `updateAttribute(4,135,'is_used_for_promo_rules',1,null);` 4 is the attribute type, 135 is attribute code id. after that your condition and the value in your case may be `'is_required',1`.

May be this `updateAttribute(3,7,'is_required',0);`

After creating upgradeData.php in setup folder run the upgrade command and check. Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to change the is_required as 0 .This should be affect in two rows in this table

Comment: I have changed in the answer. Also i give you it for example you need to check the attribute id for your attribute code code in `eav_attribute` table.